# how to move multiple paths to the left with a fluid animation between my data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would appreciate it if you can give me a hand with my code.

my code basically consists of working with 14 sensors. Each sensor has some data that I graph. In my real project I consume a web service every second and the answer is a `.JSON` of 128 elements each. I simulate the web service with the help of a timeout, in this case I am reading `3 .JSON` files, each one a second later simulating that I am consuming `3 web services`. these data are the ones that feed the information by sensor.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {  
    appendData(data);
    })
  },1000)

  setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON("data1.json", function(data) {  
     appendData(data);
    })
  },2000)
```

each machine is called as the keys to my object .JSON. There are 14 machines in total. The .JSON has the following structure: (each `.JSON of 128 elements`)

```
[{  
 "AF3":3605.1496928113393,
 "AF4":-6000.4375230516,
 "F3":1700.3827875419374,
 "F4":4822.544985821321,
 "F7":4903.330735023786,
 "F8":824.4048714773611,
 "FC5":3259.4071092472655,
 "FC6":4248.067359141752,
 "O1":3714.5106599153364,
 "O2":697.2904723891061,
 "P7":522.7300768483767,
 "P8":4050.79490288753,
 "T7":2939.896657485737,
 "T8":9.551935316881588
}]
```

each line represents a sensor, and each line I have moved to different spaces to see them in a better way.

I'm trying to have something like this in this picture. but in my case I would like to achieve something like this by taking a second to show for each request.(the program with which I made the gif, does not show the animation very fluid.)

[image]

I am trying to draw on my graph every time I receive a .JSON request. then every second I am plotting to 128 data. but I would like to generate a more smooth  animation to move the lines, among all my data received. 
currently my animation is somewhat abrupt, as you can see in the image.

how can I do it?

[image]

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/h6QrS1i8oKfy4yYwnI8B?p=preview

```
  * SIGNAL FEATURES
  * Sampling rate: 128 samples per second. Period of each sample: 7.8125 mS
  * Resolution: 14 bits (0 - 16383), LSB is a change in 0.51uV
  * Dynamic Range: 0uV to 8.355,33uV.
  * * * */

  var SAMPLING_PERIOD = 7.8125 // milliseconds
  var SAMPLING_RATE = 128      // Samples per second

  // Read from JSON
  var aData = [];

  // Plot parameters
  var timeToShow = 3; // seconds
  var limit = timeToShow * SAMPLING_RATE;   // Buffer graph

  // Variable for x-axis
  var duration = limit * SAMPLING_PERIOD;  // Sampling period of each data

  setTimeout(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {  
    appendData(data);
    })
  },1000)

  setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON("data1.json", function(data) {  
     appendData(data);
    })
  },2000)

  setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON("data2.json", function(data) {  
     appendData(data);
    })
  },3000)


  // Canvas size
  var width = 250, height = 490
  // Emotiv Channels
  var groups = {
    AF3: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#FFB6C1',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    F7: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#3AFFFF',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    F3: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#FF0000',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    FC5: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#212529',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    T7: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#FF8C00',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    P7: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#0000FF',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    O1: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#B22BEC',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    O2: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#A52A2A',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    P8: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#7FFF00',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    T8: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#FF6347',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    FC6: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#2E8B57',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    F4: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#3ACAFF',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    F8: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#FFA500',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    },
    AF4: {
      value: 0,
      color: '#008000',
      data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
        return 0
      })
    }
  }

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, limit - 1])
    .range([0, width]);   


  // Function to map values on Y-axis
  var y = d3.scale.linear() // Linear axis with domain [0,1] and range [0,1]. http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales
    .domain([0, 8355.33])      // Dynamic range will always be between [0-8355.33]
    .range([height / 14, 0]) // Map to height of one plot

  // Container for Channel names
  var ids = []
  for (var name in groups) {
    ids.push(name)
  }

  // Function to generate bands bands in the height of the canvas, one for each channel
  var band = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(ids)
    .rangeBands([0, height])   

  // Function to generate a line
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('basis')     // Interpolation with a line... Use 'basis' for B-Spline
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

  ///////// CREATE OBJECTS IN HTML
  var svg = d3.select('.graph').append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart_sensores')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', (height + 50))

  // Add lines for each data channel
  var paths = svg.append('g')
  for (var name in groups) {
    var group = groups[name];

    let g = paths.append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(0, " + (band(name)) + ")";  // Move the group to the band of the corresponding channel
          });

    // Add the line with the color and style defined in "groups"
    group.path = g.append('path')
      .data([group.data])
      .attr('class', name + ' group')
      .style('stroke', group.color)
  }

  // Periodic function to plot one sample each time.
  function appendData(data) {
    newBlockSize=data.length;

    // Append block of data
    for (var name in groups) {
      var group = groups[name]    // Take one channel
      for (var i=0; i<newBlockSize; i++){
        group.data.push(data[ i][name])
      }
      group.path.attr('d', line)    // Draw the line with the data array
    }


    /////// MOVEMENT OF THE TIME-SERIES PLOT
    var t = paths.attr('transform',null)
      .transition()
      .ease('linear')
      //.duration()
      t.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(-newBlockSize) + ')')

    // Remove oldest data block from each group
    for (var name in groups) {
      var group = groups[name]
      for (var i=0; i<newBlockSize; i++){
         group.data.shift()
      }
    }
  }//end append function
```

Comment: One thing you will want to specify is your easing function. The default is cubic-in-out: "The default easing function is "cubic-in-out" which provides suitable slow-in slow-out animation (https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_ease)" You will want linear easing if you want a constant scroll effect.

Comment: @AndrewReid but it is not very fluid. Can you help me achieve the effect I want, please? I updated the code http://plnkr.co/edit/PabwJZMRLCibnMwyRJqd?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

The problem from the animated GIF seems actually to be that the drawing and the data providing are not synchronised. So after you shoot all those 128 data on the canvas, the system has to pause a little before the next 128 are ready.

So the first step is to be sure that your **client machine** is able to plot 128 points per second per all the machines. If it can't do this, and you can't make it draw faster, **there is no solution** except subsampling and drawing less points.

But this seems not to be the case.

Then, you need to synchronize the plotting with the incoming data. You want the graphic part to take exactly the same time as the data provisioning.

Since the former depends on an unknown client's hardware and the latter depends on the server and possibly unreliable network conditions, I think you see the difficulty. We're *not* going to do this easily, with a few judicious lines of code.

## One way to do this

One way to do this is to read the timer before the plotting starts, and read it again when the plotting has completed. Say that you see that the time taken was 850 milliseconds (a thing to remember here is that **this time will vary** from client to client, and from time to time, according to client load, network conditions etc.). 850 ms is not good, because plotting will end 150ms before the next batch arrives, and the animation will stop.

So what you do is add, *this one time*, 150ms to the animation delay. The next time you'll recalculate and maybe find you need 160ms, or 140.

If you see that the time difference is negative, it means that **you don't have the time** for the animation. In that case, you may start by reducing the existing delay value.

This way, the 128 points will be plotted and the canvas moved in a single fell swoop by the D3.js animation. This means that the only adjustment you can make is right at the end, modifying the delay. It is not ideal; you're never going to have a *completely smooth* animation. There simple is no way: the only information you have comes from the cycle that has already ended, and there's no guarantee that the next cycle will take the same time (even if that's probably the way to bet).

## Another way

Another way is to have **two separate timers**. One is ran every second to read the information, and puts it into a buffer. You have then 128 points in your buffer.

The second timer is called every 7 or 8 milliseconds and reads one point from the buffer, drawing it. You don't draw all points in a batch, you draw them one at a time (or two, three, four... at a time).

To ensure that 128 calls of TimerTwo take 1000 milliseconds, which is critical for the smoothness of the operation, you have to use a [digital differential analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)) algorithm.

To reduce the overhead you can invoke TimerTwo not 128 times per second, but say 32; every iteration then needs to read and draw 4 points at once from the buffer (**of course by saying "point" I'm actually referring to a set of 14 points, one per machine**).

The risk here is that your buffer either overflows or underflows; you will need to monitor the situation (e.g. once a second, when you fill the buffer from the JSON, you check how many points are in there. Zero: you need to call TimerTwo a bit slower. More than, say, 10: you need to call it a *teensy* bit faster.

## Other random suggestions

When you trim the data array, you do so with 128 shift()'s. You can use one splice():

```
      group.data.splice(0, newBlockSize);
```

instead of

```
      for (var i=0; i<newBlockSize; i++) {
         group.data.shift()
      }
```

The animation now "freezes" at irregular intervals, *apparently* in the animation itself, but you have to be sure. Place console.debug()'s wherever suitable. The reason is probably that your estimate of 50 ms for the drawing (hence the 950ms delay interval) is **wrong on my machine**, causing the animation and the setTimeout() functions to overlap periodically. By reducing the delay to 680, the animation is *almost* smooth on my system. But the problem here (see method 1 above) is that the right value will not always be 680. The correct value is "1000 minus however many milliseconds the previous cycle took" (maybe minus four or five other milliseconds for luck). You can use Date.now() to get the current number of milliseconds from the system clock.

Do not redefine 'name' multiple times.

Comment: friend, you know that you know enough about the subject and I thank you very much. I'm trying to understand what you just explained, but I'm afraid I have difficulty implementing your code. If you could update my plunker would be great for my learning and that of others, for now I am not able to do it, also for my little knowledge in d3.js. I thank you, my friend, for taking the time to respond. I will continue trying to try to solve it. But if you wish to do so, your help is welcome.

Comment: I tried "Other random suggestions" but the animation is not yet flowing. I thank you very much for your great help, it shows that you know a lot about this.I've tried other things, but it still does not work. your knowledge amazes me if you want you can share your plunker with what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous speacker I am unable to give you some code anytime soon, as I would have to dive in very deep into the topic.

So here's just a description of how I would do it:

You just want a smooth transition between data A and data B etc.? Well, you receive data A. Now wait and count the time until you receive data B. Once data B came in, transition between data A and B smoothly within the timespan you wait between A and B before. Simultaneously, count the time until data C flys in and calculate the median of the timespans AB and BC. Then you transition between data B and data C with this median.

This is the basic algorithm:

```
1. Wait for dataset C
    - stop time between B and C
    - transition between A and B
2. Transition A-B finished OR dataset C received (whatever happens earlier)
    - if C not received: Plot nothing, continue waiting
    - if transition A-B is still running: save C
3. Transition A-B AND dataset C received
    - wait for dataset D
    - stop time between C and D
    - calculate average of timespan A-B, B-C, etc. (e.g. the 10 last timespans)
        - transition between B and C with average timespan
```

I hope I could somehow express my idea. And I also hope it fixes your problem to a certain degree!